# How to hide the Table Name and the Unique value from Model driven app Form

Tags: dynamics-crm, powerapps, powerapps-modeldriven

I am working on a Model Driven application for an internal Purpose the main aim is to show some Training and track the details of the candidates, here we have mostly used **Model Driven Forms** only and now we have few changes/suggestion from the team to remove the **Unique values of the column and Table name from from the Header of the page** and in that place they want something else to be displayed.
[image]
So my ask here is, do we have any option where we can change those values, we have tried a Java Script which is hiding the entire Header of that page, but that is not giving a good look, please find the below code that we have used for hiding.

`function DoLoad(executionContext) {`
`var formContext =executionContext.getFormContext();`
`formContext.ui.headerSection.setBodyVisible(false);`
`}`

Any suggestion will be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately Model driven powerapps form comes with a defined layout and limited customizations options. Display name field and entity name (along with form switcher) is fixed on left side.

Ref: [Form header](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-apps/maker/model-driven-apps/form-designer-header-properties?WT.mc_id=DX-MVP-5004422#form-header)

[image]

Whereas Canvas Powerapps is the free form app builder.

Another option is [Design a custom page for your model-driven app.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-apps/maker/model-driven-apps/design-page-for-model-app?WT.mc_id=DX-MVP-5004422)

You can [submit an idea](https://ideas.powerapps.com/d365community/forum/f1458c72-ae29-ed11-9db2-000d3a8c451e?WT.mc_id=DX-MVP-5004422) and the customization you’re looking for in the OOB form maybe available in the future release.