# How to hide table name on a model driven app

Tags: powerapps-modeldriven

The following is a model-driven app's form and in this form, the respective table name is "Student".

Is it possible to hide the table name "Student"?

**Actual:**

[image]

**Expected:**

[image]

EDIT:
Forgot to mention that I did take a look at another post but it feels like it might not be relevant.
[How to hide the Table Name and the Unique value from Model driven app Form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76653840/how-to-hide-the-table-name-and-the-unique-value-from-model-driven-app-form)